# Having problems

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
USE Kudler_FF
INSERT INTO Employee_Tbl
   (LastName, FirstName, Address, City, State, TelephoneAreaCode,
    TelephoneNumber, EmployeeInformationReportClassification, HireDate, Salary,
    Gender, Age, JobTitle)
VALUES
     ('Edelman', 'Glen', '175 Bishops Ln.', 'La Jolla', 'CA', '619', '5550199',
     'Sales Workers', '10/07/2003', '21000.00', 'M', '64', 'Bagger'),
     ('McMullen', 'Eric', '763 Church St.', 'Lemon Grove', 'CA', '619', '5550133',
     'Sales Workers', '10/07/2003', '13500.00', 'M', '20', 'Bagger'),
     ('Slentz', 'Raj', '123 Torrey Dr.', 'North Clairmount', 'CA', '619', '5550123',
     'Officials & Managers', '06/01/2000', '48000.00', 'M', '34','Assistant Store Manager'),
     ('Brown', 'Erin', '2045 Parkway Apt. 28', 'Encinitas', 'CA', '760', '5550100', 
     'Sales Workers', '03/12/2003', '10530.00', 'F', '24', 'Bagger'),
     ('Carpenter', 'Donald', '927 Second St.', 'Encinitas', 'CA', '619', '5550154', 
     'Offical/Clerical', '11/01/2003', '15000.00', 'M', '18', 'Accounting clerk'),
     ('Esquivez', 'David', '10983 N. Coast Hwy Apt. 902', 'Encinitas', 'CA', '760', '5550108', 
     'Sales Workers', '07/25/2003', '18500.00', 'M', '25', 'Stocker'),
     ('Sharp', 'Nancy', '10793 Montecino Rd.', 'Ramona', 'CA', '858', '55501503', 
     'Sales Workers', '07/12/2003', '21000.00', 'F', '24', 'Cashier');
```

The message that I am getting is: Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 2
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 1):

The length of one of the values you are trying to insert is greater than the size of the column.  Check your table definition and compare it to these values.

Comment: it's not really classified personal information, it is made up and I just need to know what I have done wrong

Comment: I have done a few changes but I am still getting the same message

Comment: @user1000197 try inserting 1 row at a time and see which one causes problems.  If you still cannot figure out which value is the problem, edit your question to include the table definition and the row that fails.